# Custom Scoring Function in sklearn Cross Validate

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to use a custom function for `cross_validate` which uses a specific `y_test` to compute precision, this is a different `y_test` than the actual target `y_test`.

I have tried a few approaches with `make_scorer` but I don't know how to actually pass my alternative `y_test`:

```
scoring = {'prec1': 'precision',
     'custom_prec1': make_scorer(precision_score()}

scores = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=5,scoring= scoring)
```

Can any suggest an approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found this way. Maybe the code is not optimal, sorry for this.

Okay, let we start:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

xTrain = np.random.rand(100, 100)
yTrain = np.random.randint(1, 4, (100, 1))

yTrainCV = np.random.randint(1, 4, (100, 1))

model = LogisticRegression()
```

`yTrainCV` will be used here as the custom scorer.

```
def customLoss(xArray, yArray):
    indices = xArray.index.values
    tempArray = [1 if value1 != value2 else 0 for value1, value2 in zip(xArray.values, yTrainCV[[indices]])]
    
    return sum(tempArray)

scorer = {'main': 'accuracy',
          'custom': make_scorer(customLoss, greater_is_better=True)}
```

Few tricks here:

- you need to pass to customLoss 2 values (predictions from the model + real values; we do not use the second parameter though)
- there is some game with `greater_is_better`: `True`/`False` will return either positive or negative number
- indices we get from CV in `GridSearchCV`

And...

```
grid = GridSearchCV(model,
                    scoring=scorer,
                    cv=5,
                    param_grid={'C': [1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3],
                                'class_weight': ['balanced', None]},
                    refit='custom')
    
 grid.fit(xTrain, pd.DataFrame(yTrain))
 print(grid.score(xTrain, pd.DataFrame(yTrain)))
```

- do not forget `refit` parameter in `GridSearchCV`
- we pass target array as `DataFrame` here - it will help us to detect indices in the custom loss function

Comment: Thank you so much avchauzov!! This is perfect, I highly appreciate your help. This is fantastic, I wish they would put this as an example on sklearn documentation for make_scorer

Comment: Thanks @avchauzov This solution is great and exactly addresses [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227646/can-i-get-extra-information-to-a-custom-scorer-function-in-sklearn) that had no official answers.