# Can I get extra information to a custom scorer function in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am performing a classification task which is essentially doing algorithm configuration, i.e. trying to pick a configuration (or 'mode') which is likely to make the problem-solving algorithm finish in the quickest time.

I am learning to classify the "best" configuration based on features of problem instances.  I see that scikit-learn enables you to [create your own scoring function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) to use in tuning the models.  However the `score_func` only takes the true label and the predicted label as input.

Is it possible to identify which row in the dataset a prediction came from (when passing to this custom scorer)?  That way I could figure out the performance hit of a predicted ("wrong") config and score the model accordingly.  Basically sometimes a "wrong" selection can still be very good and close to the best, but a naive classification has no way of knowing this when the classification labels are purely based on the best config.

Here's a contrived example to illustrate what I'm trying to do

```py
import random as rnd
import pandas as pd

rnd.seed('hello')

probs = [f'instance_{i}' for i in range(6)]
confs = ('analytic', 'bruteforce', 'hybrid')
times = [(p,c,60*rnd.random()) for p in probs for c in confs]

df_alltimes = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=('problem', 'config', 'time'))
print(df_alltimes)

bestrows = df_alltimes.groupby(['problem'])['time'].idxmin()
dataset = df_alltimes.loc[bestrows,['config']].\
          rename(columns={'config':'best_config'}) 

feats = [[rnd.random() for p in range(len(probs))] for f in range(5) ]
for i in range(len(feats)):
    dataset[f'feature_{i}'] = feats[i]
print(dataset)
```

```
df_alltimes:
       problem      config       time
0   instance_0    analytic  15.307044
1   instance_0  bruteforce  36.742846
2   instance_0      hybrid  35.053416
3   instance_1    analytic  57.781358
4   instance_1  bruteforce  31.723275
5   instance_1      hybrid   8.080238
6   instance_2    analytic   4.211297
7   instance_2  bruteforce  24.034830
8   instance_2      hybrid  39.073023
9   instance_3    analytic  36.325485
10  instance_3  bruteforce  14.717841
11  instance_3      hybrid  57.103908
12  instance_4    analytic   7.358539
13  instance_4  bruteforce  10.805536
14  instance_4      hybrid   2.605044
15  instance_5    analytic   0.489870
16  instance_5  bruteforce  42.888858
17  instance_5      hybrid  58.634073

dataset:
   best_config  feature_0  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4
0     analytic   0.645388   0.641626   0.975619   0.680713   0.209235
5       hybrid   0.993443   0.221038   0.893763   0.408532   0.254791
6     analytic   0.263872   0.142887   0.264538   0.166985   0.800054
10  bruteforce   0.155023   0.601300   0.258767   0.614732   0.850529
14      hybrid   0.766183   0.993692   0.597047   0.401482   0.275133
15    analytic   0.386327   0.065699   0.349115   0.370136   0.357329
```

I am using sklearn with the `dataset` where the `X` would be the feature columns and the `y` would be the `best_config` column.  In this example, the "bad" choices for `instance_0` are both almost equally bad, but for `instance_1`, the two wrong choices are not equally bad.  So I'd like my custom scorer to be able to reflect this somehow.  Is that possible?

Comment: Your question (and what exactly you mean by"config" here) is completely unclear. You "*would like to score a prediction based on the performance of the algorithm with the predicted label*" - well, this is what we *routinely* do with any scoring function.

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut, I'll try to word it better.  In the sentence you quote, I wasn't talking about the classification algorithm, but rather that the labels are a configuration/mode to run another problem-solving algorithm in.  I have timing data for all the configs, so when a config is chosen, the sklearn classification simply knows if it's the one I pre-labelled 'best'.  But I could say how "close to good" any prediction is if I could look up the timings somehow.

Comment: Please do not offer such clarifications in the comments - edit & update your question accordingly instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it - hence "I'll try to word it better".  I will try to flesh out my problem a bit more fully and edit the original question accordingly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I did find a way to get the information I was after in the original question.  If you're passing a `pandas.Series` as your target labels, the `index` attribute is available, so you can look up whatever you want in the full dataset.

In the solution below, the first part is pretty much the same as the original minimal working example - i.e. generating a fake dataset.

In the second part, a custom scorer function is defined, which is then passed to the cross-validating hyperparameter tuner, `RandomizedSearchCV`.  Please bear in mind the data is garbage, so the "results" are meaningless; this is just a demo of how to refer back to a fuller set of results so that you can evaluate the quality of predictions made during hyperparameter tuning based on more specialised information rather than just "match / fail" when doing a classification.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rnd

INSTANCES = 200
FEATURES  = 5
HP_ITER   = 10
SEED      = 1984

# invent timings for some problems run with different configurations
rnd.seed(SEED)
probs = [f'p_{i:03d}' for i in range(INSTANCES)]
confs = ('analytic', 'bruteforce', 'hybrid')
times = [(p,c,60*rnd.random()) for p in probs for c in confs]
df_times = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=('problem', 'config', 'time'))

# pick out the fastest config for each problem
bestrows = df_times.groupby(['problem'])['time'].idxmin()
dataset = df_times.loc[bestrows,['config','problem']]\
                  .rename(columns={'config':'target'})\
                  .reset_index(drop=True)

# invent some features for each problem
feats = [[rnd.random() for _ in probs] for f in range(FEATURES) ]
for i in range(len(feats)):
    dataset[f'feature_{i}'] = feats[i]


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# split our data into training and test sets
df_trn = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, replace=False, random_state=SEED)
df_tst = dataset.loc[~dataset.index.isin(df_trn.index)]

def _vb_loss(xvals, yvals, validation=False):
    """A custom scorer for cross-validation which uses distance to Virtual Best"""
    # use the .index attribute to access the relevant rows in the
    # timing data frame
    source = df_tst if validation else df_trn
    
    data = source.loc[xvals.index].reindex(columns=['problem','target'])
    data['truevals'] = xvals
    data['predvals'] = yvals

    # what's the best time available for each problem?
    data = data.merge(
        df_times, left_on=['problem','truevals'], right_on=['problem', 'config']
    ).rename(columns={'time' : 'best_time'}).drop(columns=['config'])

    # what's the time for our predicted choices?
    data = data.merge(
        df_times, left_on=['problem','predvals'], right_on=['problem','config']
    ).rename(columns={'time' : 'pred_time'}).drop(columns=['config'])

    # how far away were the predictions in total?
    residual_seconds = np.sum( data['pred_time'] - data['best_time'] )
    return residual_seconds


def fitAndPredict(use_custom_scorer=False):
    """Fit a model and make some predictions """
    our_scorer = make_scorer(_vb_loss, greater_is_better=False)
    hyperparameters = {'criterion' : ['gini', 'entropy'],
                       'n_estimators' : list(range(50,250)),
                       'max_depth' : list(range(2,32))
    }
    model = RandomizedSearchCV(
        RandomForestClassifier(random_state=SEED),
        hyperparameters,
        n_iter = HP_ITER,
        scoring = our_scorer if use_custom_scorer else None,
        verbose = 1,
        random_state = SEED,
    )
    model.fit(
        df_trn.drop(columns=['target','problem']),
        df_trn['target']
    )

    preds = model.predict(df_tst.drop(columns=['target','problem']))
    return _vb_loss(df_tst['target'], preds, validation=True)


print("Timings for all configs:", df_times, "", sep="\n")
print("Labelled dataset:", dataset, "", sep="\n")
print("Test loss with default CV scorer :", fitAndPredict(False))
print("Test loss with custom CV scorer :", fitAndPredict(True))
```

Here's the output:

```
** Timings for all configs **
    problem      config       time
0     p_000    analytic  21.811701
1     p_000  bruteforce  29.652341
2     p_000      hybrid  20.376605
3     p_001    analytic  12.989269
4     p_001  bruteforce  51.759137
..      ...         ...        ...
595   p_198  bruteforce  10.874092
596   p_198      hybrid  14.723661
597   p_199    analytic  24.984775
598   p_199  bruteforce   4.899111
599   p_199      hybrid  36.188729

[600 rows x 3 columns]

** Labelled dataset **
         target problem  feature_0  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4
0        hybrid   p_000   0.864952   0.487293   0.946654   0.863503   0.310866
1      analytic   p_001   0.514093   0.007643   0.948784   0.582419   0.258159
2    bruteforce   p_002   0.319059   0.872320   0.321495   0.807644   0.158471
3      analytic   p_003   0.421063   0.955742   0.114808   0.980013   0.900057
4        hybrid   p_004   0.325935   0.125824   0.697967   0.037196   0.923626
..          ...     ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
195      hybrid   p_195   0.179126   0.578338   0.391535   0.632501   0.442677
196  bruteforce   p_196   0.827637   0.641567   0.710201   0.833341   0.215357
197      hybrid   p_197   0.116661   0.480170   0.253893   0.623913   0.465419
198  bruteforce   p_198   0.670555   0.037084   0.954332   0.408546   0.935973
199  bruteforce   p_199   0.371541   0.463060   0.549176   0.581093   0.391114

[200 rows x 7 columns]

Fitting 5 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 50 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=None)]: Done  50 out of  50 | elapsed:    8.8s finished
Test loss with default CV scorer : 542.5191014477357
Fitting 5 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 50 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=None)]: Done  50 out of  50 | elapsed:    9.1s finished
Test loss with custom CV scorer : 522.3236277796698
```